# Connector type for automotive

Tags: connector, automotive

Does anyone know what kind of connector this is? It is used in a battery pack of a car to connect can-bus wires with each other.

The connector has 2 rows with 22 pins in total. 
Dimensions of female wire harness: 30mm x 14mm x 19mm

[image]

Comment: Looks like an ECU connector by Tyco or clone http://www.kinkong-connector.com/products/tycoampreplacementblack22pinfemaleecuautoconnectorelectricalwireconnectorsckk5221-12-18-21-ID264.html

Comment: Yes it seems to be a connector of the TE AMP series (multilock 040/070)